# Java Cash register program

Tags: java, for-loop

I have to write a cash register program. The program looks like this:

Cash register program. Please give items price, stops to input 0.
459
315
1125
3456
396
0
Sum 5751 Ft.
Average 1150,20 Ft.
Most expensive 3456 Ft.
The most expensive is 200,47%- expensive than the average.
Totally 3 items cheaper then 500 Ft.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double average = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int mostExpensive = 0;
    int smaller500 = 0;
    System.out.println("Cash register program, please give prices, stops when 0 entered");
    int prices = sc.nextInt();
    sum += prices;

    for (double i=1; prices != 0; i++)
    {
        prices = sc.nextInt();
        if (prices < 500)
        {
            smaller500++;
        }
        sum += prices;
        average = i;
        if (prices > mostExpensive )
        {
            mostExpensive = prices;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Total amount "+sum+" Ft.");
    System.out.printf("Average is %.2f Ft. %n",sum/average);
    System.out.println("Most expensive is "+mostExpensive+" Ft.");
    System.out.printf("The most expensive is %.2f%% expensive then the average.%n",(mostExpensive/(sum/atlag))*100-100);
    System.out.println("Totally "+smaller500+" pcs. cheaper then 500 FT.");
}
```

}

What's the problem with the program? If I only give one item, it doesn't matter what number given, it says 1 item is cheaper than 500 Ft.

Comment: If the strings in your code were in English it would be easier to follow what they are trying to indicate.

Comment: Sorry, your're right! Now I edited to English, hope you understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you input zero for `prices`, this is supposed to exit your loop. But before that happens, all this code gets run:

```
    prices = sc.nextInt();
    if (prices < 500)
    {
        smaller500++;
    }
    sum += prices;
    average = i;
    if (prices > mostExpensive )
    {
        mostExpensive = prices;
    }
```

which (among other things) will increment the variable `smaller500`.

You could change your loop to input `prices` at the end instead of the beginning, so your loop condition would be checked immediately; or you could simply break out of your loop when you input zero.

```
for (double i=1; prices != 0; i++)
{
    prices = sc.nextInt();
    if (prices == 0) {
        break;
    }
    if (prices < 500)
    {
        smaller500++;
    }
    sum += prices;
    average = i;
    if (prices > mostExpensive )
    {
        mostExpensive = prices;
    }
}
```